# ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Tags: django, django-forms

I am getting this error when trying to save a form:

['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Views:

```
def scoreInput1View(request):

    Input1FormSet = modelformset_factory(Player, fields=('name', 'week1'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Input1FormSet(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = Input1FormSet()

    players = Player.objects.all()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'players': players
    }

    template_name = 'leaderboard/input1.html'

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

HTML:

```
<form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>17th Score</th>
    </tr>
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for field in form %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ field.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ field.week1 }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </table>
<input type='submit' value="Save">
</form>
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Look at the html source to verify the hidden management form fields are correct. And look at `request.POST` to check what is being submitted. Note: you should check if your formset is valid before saving: `if form.is_valid(): form.save() else: ...`

Comment: note also you can't do `for field in form`, it's a formset, even if there's only one form, the iterator of a formset returns forms. so you need to nest loops: `for form in formset: for field in form:`

Comment: Using {% for field in form %} renders the page correctly, looping through the forms and then the fields doesn't render anything. The html source has nothing regarding the management forms?

Comment: sorry, your naming confused me. What you call `field` is actually a `form` and `field.name` is the `name` field of the form. Would be better to rename `form` to `formset` and loop `for form in formset`, then display the fields `form.name` and `form.week1`. But `form.management_form` should produce some hidden input fields. Maybe move that to outside of the table.

Comment: Basically, you need to make sure the data submitted contains the management form data. So check the HTML source, and check the `request.POST` data.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Comment: Moving the ```form.management_form``` outside of the table did the trick! Thanks for your help!